# @GenerationType.IDENTITY failing above 10

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb, identity

I'm working in a project where I need to store some data (among other things, of course). The production DB will be **MySQL** but for my tests I'm using [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org) (aka HSQLDB).

All my `@Enitity` classes has the corresponding `@Id` field with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to let the DB generate that field. Everything was working fine until I tried to load some amount of data in HSQLDB and got the error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
    violación del restricción de integridad: 
    violación de índice o clave única; UK_... table: OPERACION
```

The message *"violación del restricción de integridad: violación de índice o clave única"* means *"integrity constraint violation: primary key or unique index violation"* (I don't know if that's the message when Locale is set to English, but the translation is that)

I set the logger to `TRACE` to get a full picture and realized that in table `OPERACION` generates the `id` field up to 10 with no problem, but in the 11th registry it gives me the message `SqlExceptionHelper:139 - could not execute statement [n/a]` and then raises the exception.

Is there any way to configure `HSQLDB` to generates more `@Id` values with `IDENTITY`? Is this something with the `@GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy or with the DB itself? Is there any issue with the chosen strategy that I must take into account in a production environment?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

### Edit #1

I've been swimming in the HyperSQL documentation and in the last version (and previous also) it supports identity generation. Just in case, I switched to the last version `2.3.4` (I was using `2.3.2`) but the result is the same.

Also I tried with the `@GenerationType.AUTO` strategy but the error remains. Maybe there's any configuration I can use in `persistence.xml` to tell HSQLDB how many identities it must generate but I still don't find anything. If someone knows that property please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check that the table already contains record which has the primary key=10? Can you delete all records from the table and run your program? I think the table already contains record with PK=10.

Comment: That's not the case, I configured a `persistence.xml` for my test cases with the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property set to `create-drop`, so in every test case I get a DB with empty tables. Also note that in the `OPERACION` table JPA (I'm using Hibernate as implementation) generates id from 1 to 10 with no problem, the exception raises when the id=11 should be generated, am I explaining correctly?